# Show that matrix is totally unimodular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, determinant, total-unimodularity

I want to show that this matrix is totally unimodular:

\begin{bmatrix}
   1  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0  & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

I do laplace expansion by first row and I get:

\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

Then laplace expansion by last row and get:

\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1  & 0  & 0  & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

So it sufficces to show that this matrix is totally unimodular.

Do I need to show that **every square** submatrix is unimodular?

I.e. this matrix has 4x4=16 submatrices of size (n-1) which can be computed by Sarrus rule?

**What I did incorrectly** was, I went one more laplace expansion, to get 3x3 and then Sarrused it, but I guess it is not correct, am I right?

How can I show that this 4x4 is totally unimodular? ( I know because R told me)

Could you show it by **partitioning it to B,C** or somehow with incidence matrices of Graphs?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your questions in the order that you asked them:

You do need to show that ***every*** square sub-matrix of your original matrix (before the Laplace expansions) has a determinant = $\pm1,$ or 0. Notice that if the -1 in your original matrix were a -5, the matrix would no longer be TUM, despite not changing the determinant of the entire matrix, so even though the $4 \times 4$ matrix is TUM, it is not sufficient proof that the larger matrix is TUM.

I am not familiar with Sarrus's rule, so I can't comment there.

As for the final 4 $\times$ 4 matrix, you can consider it to be the incidence matrix of a 4 node graph. Partition the nodes into two groups, $B,C$ such that there are no edges between any nodes in $B$, and there are no edges between any nodes in $C$. Doing so shows that your graph is bipartite, and thus its adjacency matrix is TUM.